# Piezoelectric sensor in the disc brake balancing machine shows 50 hz wave when idle. How to remove this noise, I want to get only piezo waveform?

Tags: filter, circuit-design, signal, noise, oscilloscope

I'm working on a machine which detects rotational imbalance based on readings from a piezo electric sensor. I have connected piezo with a charge amplifier (op amp based), the output of which shows 50 hz waveform on oscilloscope even if machine is not working. The 3 phase motor in machine is powered via VFD.
 Is there any way to get rid of this noise as I want to see waveform of sensor only?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a ground somewhere. You would need to sketch out your setup of schematic for a better answer. We can't see what you can see.

Comment: We always used bees wax to adhere accelerometers to a shaker table and ground STP (shielded twisted pair) cable to amplifier. you might consider sharing your charge amp schematic and all grounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use special semi-rigid shielded twisted pair to protect high impedance inputs.

Shield, Earth and amplifier ground must be chosen carefully to prevent sharing any ground current with machines or other equipment line noise filters. Normally Earth grounded at instrument but shield terminated only at sensor end to earth ground under sensor.

The reason for stiffness is that any cable vibration will look like a change in C or charge just like the Piezo.

Piezo devices have high resistance making the wires good antenna to power lines which also make good antenna and the crosstalk is due to this high input impedance needed to prevent loss of charge.

Another possible solution is to add large Clamshell Ferrite CM choke around cable to raise the CM impedance and thus allow 50Hz to cancel by coupling to each wire equally, but I doubt this will work unless design is carefully analyzed for impedance.

### Simplified differential Charge Amp.

- showing shielded pair cable.

[image]

Here T= RC=540e6 *240e-12= 0.13  with f-3dB(hpf)=0.35/T = ~ 3Hz

Comment: One could also add another, mechanically unconnected piezo and subtract the error signals.

Comment: It is the high Z wire that picks up the signal more on 1 side, so the wire and charge amp Differential, Common Mode Z needs to be balanced.  i.e. not single ended charge amp.

Comment: Should I connect ground wire of machine with ground of power supply?

Comment: Show your schematic

Comment: Thanks I realize now, I earthed both machine as well as oscilloscope then used shielded wire noise was significantly removed. Thank you, GOD bless you

Answer (score 0):

Try to place amplifier as close to the sensor as possible, and use good shielding, because electric line between them is subject of electro-magnetic interference from power devices.